# Maven problem with ManageDependencies with Multi-Layer Projects

Tags: java, maven

Say I have a multi-layer Maven project with two modules and five leaves. (My project actually has 14 modules and 78 leaves but my question can be asked with just two.)

The parent POM builds the modules and uses *dependencyManagement* to define my 3rd-party dependencies.

In the Module POMs I use *dependencyManagement* to declare my 'internal' dependencies (e.g. *Module_A* is 'common' and *Module_A2* depends on *Module_A1*)

```
parent POM
 |  -- DependencyManagement
 |    -- 3rd party dependencies (e.g. commons-logging, junit)
 |
 +-+-- Module_A POM
 | |   -- DependencyManagement 
 | |      -- Project inter-dependencies (Module_A1, Module_A2)
 | |
 | +---- Module_A1 POM
 | +---- Module_A2 POM (depends on _A1)
 | +---- Module_A3 POM (depends on _A1, _A2)
 |
 +-+-- Module_B POM
   |   -- DependencyManagement 
   |      -- Project inter-dependencies (Module_A1, Module_B1)
   |
   +---- Module_B1 POM (depends on _A1)
   +---- Module_B2 POM (depends on _A1, _B1)
```

Each leaf (*Module_A1 .. Module_B2*) declares its dependencies without version. Parent dependencies are declared the whole way up and AFAICT this is a clean Maven structure and everything mostly works as expected.

I can build *Module_A* no problem from *Module_A*'s folder and everything works. It finds *commons-logging* declared at the parent POM level and A1/A2 work just fine. So syntactically I am OK. But if I step up to the parent POM and try to build the whole project, I fail with *Module_A* complaining about **dependencies.dependency.version** for my project inter-dependencies. The exact ones that worked from the *Module_A* folder when I called *Module_A/pom.xml* directly instead of through the parent POM. Even if I try to execute just *Module_A/pom.xml* from the Parent folder via *-pl Module_A* it fails. So running Maven via the parent *POM.xml* file breaks *Module_A/POM.xml*.

This implies you cannot use *dependencyManagement* at TWO levels of a project, though I cannot find anything that tells me not to. If this is the case I appear to have two choices:

A) Move my project internal inter-dependencies up to the parent *POM.xml*. If I do this, It feels like I'm fully specifying ALL of my dependencies at the top and I'll have a cluttered parent POM that over-specifies my project.

B) Remove the *dependencyManagement* tag from *Module_A* and specify the modules directly, but then I'm including all declared modules in the leaf POMs (*Module_A1*, etc.) which is not what I want. (I KNOW THIS ONE IS BAD)

I realize *dependencyManagement* is really just a series of variable declarations so I'm probably not hurting anything if I move my internal dependencies to the parent POM, but that feels sloppy. Like I didn't know well enough to cleanly segregate my module dependencies by sub-system and punted them all to the top-most POM.

I know there are projects WAY more complicated than mine. All I can see is hundreds of dependencies dumped into the parent POM making an ugly mess. In my case, I'd be defining most of my 78 leaf modules in the parent POM and that feels like the wrong way to do it. Is there a better way or is this the intent of the Parent POM? To specify everything about the environment and let all the lower modules define as little as possible?

Comment: You should a dependency with a version like `${project.version}` but of course only for dependencies which are inside your structure. And in this case you should simply use `<dependencies>..</dependencies>` instead of `<dependencyManagement>...`

Comment: I completely agree with standardizing internal dependencies via a version variable, but I understood the function of dependencyManagement as a way to centralize dependencies regardless of version. Yes, I can push them all the way back down to the leaves but that doesn't seem to be 'The Maven Way', unless I'm misunderstanding how to manage my internal dependencies...

Comment: So when I check the effective POM of Module_A, it correctly pulls in the Parent POM's dependencies into one combined dependencyManagement block, which is what I expected. 

Running the same command on the Parent POM results in the same failure, meaning POMs included via <module> are NOT integrated into the current POM. So my structure is OK but Maven does not pull dependencyManagement dependencies up into the current POM, only down from the parent.